# what is this “first inode” reported by dumpe2fs?

Tags: linux, ext4, inode, ext2

using dumpe2fs on some ext4 partition, I get in the initial data, that the first inode is #11. However, if I `ls -i` on this disk root partition, I get that it's inode number is #2 (as expected). So... What is this “first partition” reported by dumpe2fs ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#11 is the first "non-special" inode, that can be used for the first regularly created file or directory (usually used for `lost+found`). The number of that inode is saved in the filesystem superblock (`s_first_ino`), so technically it doesn't need to be #11, but `mke2fs` always sets it that way.

Most of the inodes from #0 to #10 have special purposes (e.g. #2 is the root directory) but some are reserved or used in non-upstream versions of the ext filesystem family. The usages are documented on [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/ext4/overview.html#special-inodes).

| inode Number | Purpose |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | n/a |
| 1 | List of defective blocks |
| 2 | Root directory |
| 3 | User quota |
| 4 | Group quota |
| 5 | Reserved for boot loaders |
| 6 | Undelete directory (reserved) |
| 7 | "resize inode" |
| 8 | Journal |
| 9 | "exclude" inode (reserved) |
| 10 | Replica inode (reserved) |

Answer (score 3):

Inode #1 -> #10 are "Reserved".  From that reserved block #2 is the "root" directory of the filesystem

So #11 is typically the first real inode allocated... and that is probably `lost+found`

So:

```
% ls -ali / | awk '$1<=11'
 2 dr-xr-xr-x. 18 root root  4096 Jul 24  2019 ./
 2 dr-xr-xr-x. 18 root root  4096 Jul 24  2019 ../
 2 dr-xr-xr-x.  6 root root  4096 May  1 22:21 boot/
 3 drwxr-xr-x  17 root root  2980 Jun 30 20:49 dev/
11 drwx------.  2 root root 16384 Jul 24  2019 lost+found/
 1 dr-xr-xr-x  90 root root     0 Jun 30 20:49 proc/
 1 dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root     0 Jun 30 20:49 sys/
```

The directories `boot` `dev` `proc` and `sys` are all mountpoints, so the `ls` output is showing the inode numbers inside those filesystems.  That leaves `.` and `..` as #2 and `lost+found` as #11

In early versions of ext2 this reserved count was fixed.  In later versions it's configurable in the superblock, and that's the value that `dump2fs` is reporting.